# Remove everything that is not a email adress with Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have lines that contain email adresses and hidden variations of email adresses, for example, use of `[at]` instead of `@`. I would like clean this list from everything that is not a email adress.

The TLDs is `.com`, `.us` and `.me`

Sample input

```
johndoe@example.com
johndoe @example.us
contant johndoe @ example . me
my email is johndoe@example.com
johndoe@example.com is my email
this johndoe @ example.com is my mail
johndoe[at]example.com 
my email is johndoe [at] example.com
johndoe[at-sign]example.com
johndoe at example.com
johndoe[at-sign]example[dot]com is my mail
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, johndoe[at-sign]example[dot]us 
johndoe[at-sign]example[dot]me labore et dolore magna aliqua
Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt johndoe at example dot com
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate  JOHNDOE at EXAMPLE dot US aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum johndoe at example dot me
```

I am using Notepad++ search and replace and my try is this `[\w]+(|\s)(@|at|\[at\]|\[at-sign\])(|\s)[\w]+(|\s)(\.|dot)(|\s)(com|us|me)` and it seem to work on everything but not line 11, 12, 13 and 15.

Wrote this on my own and, is this the right way?

Desired output:

```
johndoe@example.com
johndoe@example.us
johndoe @ example . me
johndoe@example.com
johndoe@example.com
johndoe@example.com
johndoe[at]example.com 
johndoe [at] example.com
johndoe[at-sign]example.com
johndoe [at-sign] example.com
johndoe[at-sign]example[dot]com
johndoe[at-sign]example[dot]us 
johndoe[at-sign]example[dot]me
johndoe at example dot com
JOHNDOE at EXAMPLE dot US
johndoe at exampledotme
```

I don't expect this to be 100% bulletproof since I have read that [e-mail validation can be hard](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: Will there always be one and only one email per line?

Comment: My email ends in `.net` and is perfectly valid, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your regex a bit, and what's wrong with the one you're using is that you are not matching the square parentheses around the `dot`:

```
\w+\s?(?:@|at|\[at(?:-sign)?\])\s?\w+\s?(?:\.|\[dot\]|dot)\s?(?:com|us|me)
                                              ^^^^^^^
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/mI2pZ6)

Though if you want to remove everything else, you might use this:

```
^(?:.*?(\w+ ?(?:@|at|\[at(?:-sign)?\]) ?\w+ ?(?:\.|\[dot\]|dot) ?(?:com|us|me)).*|.*)$
```

And replace with `$1`.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kB2qS2)

Comment: Wow, amazing Jerry. Your second "remove everything else" solution seem to work great in regex101 but when replacing in Notepad++ the fifteenth line (that contains `JOHNDOE at EXAMPLE dot US` disappears completely. It it because of case sensitivity?

Comment: @LiuKang Yup, you need to match with case insensitivity. There's the `US` which is in block letters. Notice that I also used the `i` flag in regex101 for that same reason.